# Python Name Error 'Name' is not defined within nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, tree

I am creating a decision tree via a nested dictionary but am subject to the error

11:{'Q':'Coffee or tea?', 'A':{'Coffee': Coffee, 'Tea': Tea}},
NameError: name 'Coffee' is not defined. When I comment out dictionary 11 I face the error

12:{'Q':'Iced Coffee or Iced Tea?', 'A': {'IcedCoffee:': IcedCoffee, 'Iced Tea': IcedTea}},
NameError: name 'IcedCoffee' is not defined

I am incorrectly referencing the dict in the previous' value dict?

```
#Decision tree implemented as nested linked dictionary
decision_tree_1 = {


0:{'Q':'Would you like to order?', 'A':{'Yes': 1, 'No': 2}},
1:{'Q':'Category ?', 'A':{'Hot Drink': 11, 'Cold Drink': 12,'Food': 13}},
11:{'Q':'Coffee or tea?', 'A':{'Coffee': Coffee, 'Tea': Tea}},
12:{'Q':'Iced Coffee or Iced Tea?', 'A': {'IcedCoffee:': IcedCoffee, 'Iced Tea': IcedTea}},
13:{'Q':'Sandwich or Pastry', 'A': {'Sandwich': Sandwich, 'Pastry': Pastry}},

S:{'Q':'What size?', 'A':{'Small': S1, 'Medium': M,'Large': L}},

Q:{'Q':'What quantity?', 'A':{'1': One, '2': Two,'3': Three}},

Coffee:{'Q':'Coffee', 'A':{}},
Tea:{'Q':'Tea', 'A':{}},
IcedCoffee:{'Q':'Iced Coffee', 'A':{}},
IcedTea:{'Q':'Iced Tea', 'A':{}},
Sandwich:{'Q':'Sandwich', 'A':{}},
Pastry:{'Q':'Pastry', 'A':{}},

S1:{'Q':'Small', 'A':{}},
M:{'Q':'Medium', 'A':{}},
L:{'Q':'Large', 'A':{}},

One:{'Q':'1', 'A':{}},
Two:{'Q':'2', 'A':{}},
Three:{'Q':'3', 'A':{}},

}
```

Comment: Well, it *isn't* defined. So what are you expecting?

Comment: Have I not defined it in line Coffee:{'Q':'Coffee', 'A':{}}, ?

Comment: No, that isn't a variable, `dict` keys are hashable objects, and they don't become variables.  And in fact, that would *also throw a `NameError`*, it just hasn't reached that part yet during parsing the dict literal

Comment: you have `'IcedCoffee:'` but should be `'Iced Coffee'`, I think.

Comment: you have to create variable using `Coffee = ...`. Using `Coffee:{'Q':'Coffee', 'A':{}}` can't create variable `Coffee`. You should first create `"Coffee":{'Q':'Coffee', 'A':{}}` using string `"Coffee"` instead of variable `Coffee` and later use `decision_tree_1["Coffee"]` in other places - ie. `'A':{'Coffee': decision_tree_1["Coffee"]`,`

Answer (score 2):

Barewords, that is, just some letters sitting in your file like `Coffee`, are only valid Python expressions if they are part of an assignment statement, or if they have been previously bound to a value.

I think the kind of self-referential structure you are trying to build here is not well-served by a python dict with string keys. You should probably consider creating a DecisionTree class of some kind, so that its nodes can reference each other the way you want.

Comment: Please could you link some resources for a DecisionTree class. Regards

Comment: You could try reading this I guess http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch21.html

There are tons of resources on similar topics, I don't know exactly what will work best for you. This is just something I found quickly by googling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a subset of your decision tree with better indentation, only show things relating to coffee:

```
dt = {
  11:{
    'Q':'Coffee or tea?', 
    'A':{'Coffee': Coffee, 'Tea': Tea}
  },
  Coffee:{
    'Q':'Coffee', 
    'A':{}
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this will get a `NameError` because when you first use `Coffee` on line 4, you haven't yet defined it. Then you attempt to define it on line 6, but that will give a `NameError` as well, for the same reason.

You could define something by quoting the second `Coffee`, but I think instead you should move the Coffee definition outside the decision tree.

```
coffee = {
  'Q':'Coffee', 
  'A':{}
}
tea = ...

dt = {
  11:{
    'Q':'Coffee or tea?', 
    'A':{'Coffee': coffee, 'Tea': tea}
  },
  ...
}
```